# No component found with scheme: smtp

Tags: java, osgi, apache-camel

I've added `camel-mail` maven dependency ([as proposed](http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/Failed-to-resolve-endpoint-smtp-krishna-aradhya-cognizant-com-due-to-No-component-found-with-scheme-p-td5729156.html)), still getting

```
No component found with scheme: smtp
```

It is working in test but not at runtime. What I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

If the component package is missing from the Felix [maven-bundle-plugin](http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html) configuration, the plugin will not expose the needed bundle in the generated MANIFEST.MF.

```xml
  <Import-Package>
    ...
    org.apache.camel.component.mail,
```

Answer (score 0):

If you deploy the route into OSGi container, you need to make sure the camel-mail bundle is installed.